# Ruby on Rails: How to add a form text field if the corresponding filed in the model doesn't exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following models:

```
Product: name, shop_id (foreign key)
Shop:    name
```

The associations are:

```
Product: belongs_to :shop
Shop:    has_many   :products
```

In the form that creates a new `Product` I have:

```
<%= f.label(:shop, "Shop:") %>
<%= f.select(...) %>
```

This is a select box with all existing shops. The last option in this select box is `Create New Shop`. When user clicks this option, Javascript shows an extra field:

```
<div id="new_shop_wrapper">
    <label for="new_shop">New shop:</label>
    <input id="new_shop" name="new_shop" type="text" />
</div>
```

(This `div` is hidden by default with `display: none`.)

How should I add this `div` in the Rails form creation ?

I tried:

```
<%= f.label(:new_shop, "New Shop:") %>
<%= f.text_field(:new_shop) %>
```

but it doesn't work because `new_shop` is not `Product`'s field.

I thought to use:

```
<%= text_field(<object>, :new_shop) %>
```

but I don't know what  to use.

Please advise.

Comment: You'd probably get more traction if the title of your question was a question :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
<%= text_field_tag("new_shop") %>
```

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you could add your method in the model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def new_show=(val)
    self.shop = Shop.new({:name => val})
  end
end
```